# Отобразить Mysql запрос

Tags: php, mysql

Как получить четыре логина, соответствующих данным id? Сейчас код такой:

```php
mysql_query("SELECT login FROM name WHERE id = '$array[0]' OR id = '$array[1]' OR id = '$array[2]' OR id = '$array[3]' LIMIT 4");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В части SQL вам лучше, вероятно, запрашивать пары `id - login`, иначе не понятно, к какому id какой login относится:

```
SELECT id, login FROM name WHERE id IN (?,?,?,?);
```

Вместо вопросительных знаков надо подставить ваши значения. `mysql_query()` использует устаревшее расширение PHP, которое скоро будет исключено из работы. Используйте [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php) или [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-mysql.php). С PDO будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1', 'username', 'password');    
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT id, login FROM name WHERE id IN (?,?,?,?)');
$sth->execute( $array); // ваш массив с 4 значениями
$logins = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Результатом будет массив, содержащий до 4 строк, если все найдутся, с ассоциативными массивами для каждой найденной строки. Т.е. для первой пары вы можете забрать:

```
$login1 = $logins[0]['login'];
$id1 = $logins[0]['id'];
```